# Streamlining Multiple Open Scripts in RStudio into a Single Consolidated Script

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, we have the flexibility to operate multiple scripts simultaneously, each opened in a separate tab. These scripts may serve different functions and contribute to various aspects of our project.

However, there may be circumstances where consolidating these multiple scripts into one singular script is desired, as it can enhance the readability and manageability of the project.

The question that arises then is: Is it possible to achieve this amalgamation of scripts automatically, without having to copy and paste the contents manually?

Let's take an illustrative scenario where we have three distinct scripts opened in RStudio: script1, script2, and script3, each with its unique code. Our aim is to create a fourth script, script4, that would encompass the code from all three scripts. How might we proceed to accomplish this task efficiently?

Comment: simple option: `source("script1.R"); sourc("script2.R");...` more advanced could be to use the `targets` package.

Comment: @JonSpring. Thank you. Maybe I was not clear. I need the whole text of the 3 scripts in one script?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make this a more robust function:

```r
list.files(pattern = "script\\d+.R") |>
  lapply(readLines) |>
  unlist() |>
  paste(collapse = "\n") |>
  writeLines(con = file("appended.R"))
```

*Script 1*

```r
# code comment
df <- iris # code comment
x <- "virginica"
```

*Script 2*

```r
df2 <- subset(df, Species == x)
```

*Script 3*

```r
write.csv(df2, "output.csv")
```

**Output**

```r
# code comment
df <- iris # code comment
x <- "virginica"
df2 <- subset(df, Species == x)
write.csv(df2, "output.csv")
```

---

On Windows you can do

```r
shell("copy script1.R+script2.R+script3.R appended.R)
```

OR

```r
shell("copy script* appended.R")
```

Unless the files end with a newline it will concatenate them together like:

```r
# code comment
df <- iris # code comment
x <- "virginica"df2 <- subset(df, Species == x)write.csv(df2, "output.csv")
```

You can set files to end with a newline to be the default option under Tools > Global Options > Code > Saving > Ensure that source file ends with newline

That might not help with existing files. One really hacky way around this would be to save a text file with only a new line and then do:

```
shell("copy script1.R+newline.txt+script2.R+newline.txt+script3.R appended.R")
```

Comment: This is a good option. I think i never used readLines and writeLines!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, in the command line you can do

```
cat script1.R script2.R > combined.R
```

or in interactive R session

```
system('cat script1.R script2.R > combined.R')
```